# Error 502 with Laravel when exporting to Excel on Azure Web App Linux

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel App running on Azure Web App Linux service, all running nice and smoothly until I reach a feature that exports a query to an XLS for download. Then I receive the ERROR 502.

On my local environment works normally, I can export the query to XLS with no issues, it is not a large query, just a few rows.

In the same app, I have a function that exports to XLS just 1 row at a time and works fine, so it is just when I go for a larger(ish) query.

Any ideas? I have tried scaling up, restarting the app, apache, changed .ini (via .htaccess to increase execution time).

There is no trace in the logs either, there is something about the container crashing but cannot trace it to this particular error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, managed to solved it... was not straight forward at all. It has to do with the size of the query, even tough is not big by any means (a couple thousands max) raising memory limit to 1024M or further ended up in 502 Error. Decided to try different and moved from Laravel Excel to Fast-Excel which is less featured but man... it works. Now everything downloads perfectly. In case you are having this issue give fast-excel a try.